# Why isn't there the cookie sent for cross domain request?

Tags: cookies, cors, htmx

I have the following setup:

- [www.localhost.lan](http://www.localhost.lan) -> 127.0.0.1
- app.localhost.lan -> 127.0.0.1

There is a haproxy running on port 443 using mkcert certificates. In the proxy the www request are sent to the static site engine the app requests are sent to the Rust backend.

```
use_backend www if { hdr(host) -i www.localhost.lan }
use_backend app if { hdr(host) -i app.localhost.lan }
```

The full config is here: https://gist.github.com/l1x/ab941cedecd85ba9a8b44046367e1d1a

When a user logs in we issue a cookie:

```
          let cookie = Cookie::build(("vs-jwt", &s))
                .domain(".localhost.lan")
                .secure(true)
                .same_site(SameSite::None)
                .http_only(true)
                .path("/")
                .max_age(Duration::WEEK)
                .build();
```

[image]

When I am navigating to [www.localhost.lan/app](http://www.localhost.lan/app) the following happens:

- GET [www.localhost.lan/app](http://www.localhost.lan/app) -> cookie is sent
- GET app.localhost.lan/view/app -> cookie is not sent

Cookie sent:

[image]

Cookie not sent:

[image]

What am I missing?

I was trying to fiddle with the cookie settings but I think it should work. Does it matter if the request was initiated by JS (HTMX in this case)?

The code that is actually triggering the GET request:

```html
<section class="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900">

    <div id="app">
    </div>

    <div hx-get="https://app.localhost.lan/view/app" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="#app">
      <img alt="Result loading..." class="htmx-indicator" width="150" src="/img/bars.svg" />
    </div>

  </section>
```

I have narrowed it down to HTMX. The standard request works:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://app.localhost.lan/view/app", true);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

This sends the cookie.

Comment: Add the relevant client code running on `https://www.localhost.lan` that sends a request to `https://app.localhost.lan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out by default the AJAX requests do not send cookies.

The default JS libs have the following:

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

In HTMX this has to be configured as well:

```html
 <div 
hx-get="https://app.localhost.lan/view/app" 
hx-request='{"credentials": true}' 
hx-trigger="load"
hx-target="#app">
      <img alt="Result loading..." 
      class="htmx-indicator" 
      width="150" src="/img/bars.svg" />
</div>
```